# What values can I use in a C - string?

Tags: c

I am facing the following code:

```
char buf[100];
char buf2[100];
strcpy( buf, "áéíóúç" );
sprintf(buf2, "%s", buf);
```

And I was wondering if it is correct or not. I've tested it in Windows and Linux and it did work, but will it work in all OS/platform of different languages?

Both `strcpy` and `sprintf` expects a C-string terminated by a `null` character, but can the content of the C-string be anything (excluding the `null` character)?

Is it ok to also do something like:

```
strcpy( buf, "\x0a\x09\x08\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01\x00" );
sprintf(buf2, "%s", buf);
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A char array is just an array of bytes, and all the non-wide string functions operate on that assumption. The only byte in general that has a special meaning is the null byte.

The C standard, as far as I can remember, doesn't have much to say on the subject of character encodings (or text in general), so your program is bound to fail on a platform where the expected output character encoding doesn't match your code.

Answer (score 2):

This question is in place, but:

The string functions are stopping only at the NULL character, as the definition of c-string is null-terminated byte buffer. So your example is OK.

Answer (score 2):

`char` is the smallest addressable unit in the machine. On anything you use today that's going to be 8 bits, or one byte. You can put anything in it that is represented by an 8 bit integer.

When dealing with character sets, there *are* sets that use 16 bits per character (characters in the charset). In that case, you have a problem if weren't aware of that and your buffer was too small to hold data.

Suggested reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. *

*) Note however that the second example will be one character short, the `\0` character indicates the end of the string and as such won't be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Almost always, your code will work.

However, I see two possible minor issues:

1. some old C compilers might not accept a C source code outside of ASCII - or maybe EBCDIC on strange mainframes -  characters (so accentuated characters might be not welcome, even in strings and comments).
2. Even on a recent Linux system, you might compile with an UTF8 encoding, but your executable would be run with a different encoding (eg ISO8859-1) and localization.

In practice, these points are minor today, since recent GCC compilers accept UTF8, and most Linux are UTF8. I won't bother in practice.

<sup>perhaps learning about internationalization and `gettext` et al. might be useful</sup>